# Canvas on IE8 with XCanvas and Doctype HTML not working

Tags: internet-explorer, canvas

Animation on page using canvas with xcanvas polyfill and requestAnimationFrame polyfill (http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) works ONLY when there is no DOCTYPE on page (?!)

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

My answer is: Don't try to code canvas animation for IE<9. (Seriously--Don't!)

The market share of IE<9 is dropping because Microsoft is exerting great efforts to update outdated IE with modern IE. Their efforts are working and IE<9 market share is negligible.  Plus trying to "bolt-on" modern technology to outdated browsers will often fail on the clients you're trying to serve.

Instead, give IE<9 clients a nice-but-not-animated screen capture of the animation results. Please help the development community wipe out outdated browsers by insisting your employers & clients to update to modern browsers rather than enabling outdated browsers with new code. :-)

If you must support animation in IE<9, use Flash.